# Available Android device sensors list

Tags: android, android-sensors

My phone has the following list of sensors:

```
 BMA150 3-axis Accelerometer, Type: 0, Vendor: The Android Open Source Project, Version: 1, Power: 3.0, Resolution: 2.480159E-4, Max Range: 2.8
 AK8973 3-axis Magnetic field sensor, Type: 0, Vendor: The Android Open Source Project, Version: 1, Power: 6.7, Resolution: 1.0, Max Range: 2000.0
 AK8973 Orientation sensor, Type: 0, Vendor: The Android Open Source Project, Version: 1, Power: 9.7, Resolution: 1.0, Max Range: 360.0
 APDS9900 Proximity sensor, Type: 8, Vendor: AVAGO, Version: 1, Power: 0.5, Resolution: 1.0, Max Range: 1.0
 APDS Light sensor, Type: 5, Vendor: AVAGO, Version: 1, Power: 0.5, Resolution: 1.0, Max Range: 10240.0
 MPL rotation vector, Type: 11, Vendor: Invensense, Version: 1, Power: 0.5, Resolution: 1.0, Max Range: 10240.0
 MPL linear accel, Type: 10, Vendor: Invensense, Version: 1, Power: 0.5, Resolution: 1.0, Max Range: 10240.0
 MPL gravity, Type: 9, Vendor: Invensense, Version: 1, Power: 0.5, Resolution: 1.0, Max Range: 10240.0
 MPL Gyro, Type: 4, Vendor: Invensense, Version: 1, Power: 0.5, Resolution: 1.0, Max Range: 10240.0
 MPL accel, Type: 1, Vendor: Invensense, Version: 1, Power: 0.5, Resolution: 1.0, Max Range: 10240.0
 MPL magnetic field, Type: 2, Vendor: Invensense, Version: 1, Power: 0.5, Resolution: 1.0, Max Range: 10240.0
 MPL Orientation (android deprecated format), Type: 3, Vendor: Invensense, Version: 1, Power: 9.7, Resolution: 1.0, Max Range: 360.0
```

of this I wonder, why are there two sensors for the accelerometer, two magnetic and two orientation sensors from which the active one is deprecated?

Does these dormant sensors has any function?

Thanks,

Adam Zehavi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly advise to use only standard Android sensors like

Rotation Vector Sensor,
Gravity Sensor,
Linear Acceleration Sensor,
Orientation Sensor

and not the MPL types. The MPL types are component specific non-standard functions from Invensense that will not work on other phones.

Also, I tried out both types on my Galaxy Nexus and found that the above listed standard Android sensors provide better sensor data fusion results than the MPL types. 
E.g. the Rotation Vector Sensor compensates magnetic distortions better that the MPL rotation vector.

Comment: MPL typed linear acceleration sensor, gravity sensor, etc. uses hardware chip to calculate the result. However, standard android sensor uses CPU, so it means using standard sensor may affect performance, and consumes more battery.

Answer (score 3):

Your phone only has one set of physical sensors, but different libraries may read it and provide an interface to Android.  The MPL sensors are using the Invensense Motion Processing Library, which fuses data from the sensors and provides a (hopefully improved) filtered result.  My guess is that the Android sensors provide something close to the raw data from the sensor.

The orientation sensor type as a whole is deprecated, not just one specific sensor.  The term "orientation" refers to portrait/landscape, which is easily confused with the rotation vector sensor, which returns a full 3D orientation.

For the best compatibility, don't hardcode the use of a specific sensor.  Use the [SensorManager.getDefaultSensor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getDefaultSensor%28int%29) method and use the properties of the sensor to adjust your application's behavior if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have for example 2 orientation sensors, but one is type 0 another type 3.
I only develop Delphi Xe5 Android applications and there type of sensor declares sensor functions. For example Orientation type 0: Compass 1D, type 3: Inclinometer1D.

I think it works similar in Java like in XE5?

Documentation for XE5 is very leak, but another proof for it is that code from IDE Demos Application: LSensorArray := TSensorManager.Current.GetSensorsByCategory(ASensorCategory); GetSensorsByCategory() results with array of sensors from given category...

Comment: Documentation for XE5 is very leak, but another proof for it is that code from IDE Demos Application:

`LSensorArray := TSensorManager.Current.GetSensorsByCategory(ASensorCategory);`

GetSensorsByCategory() results with array of sensors from given category...